# Android, Unexpected button left and right paddings

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to make a button, where left right top and bottom paddings will be same.
But I get something like this:

[image]

Here is a layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/people_number_label"
                  android:text="@string/number_of_people"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/people_number"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/people_number_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do change something in the code?

Comment: There is no changes in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the way a Button works is its a text view with a background drawable.  That drawable is the one you're seeing.  The text will be centered within that drawable, as you see here. If you want the text to appear in line with the prompt, a Button isn't going to work for you.  You're better off just making it a TextView and setting an xml background drawable with a rounded rect so it looks like a button, but it actually isn't.

Another thing you can try to do it align_baseline the two view.  That should align the text, but may push the prompt down the screen